# play/pause button in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

//how can i return the symbol of pause button in the end of Movie Clip ,it back to a play button ?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stop();
play1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playbutt);


function playbutt(event:MouseEvent):void{
    MovieClip(root).play();
    MovieClip(root).am.play();
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question as it is not clear what you are asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but from what I gather is that you need to add a listener to whatever you have playing, and then execute a gotoAndStop(1); How you do this however depends on what you are playing and what would be the most effient way of listening for its completion.

If you are playing music or a video, there is usually a Object.COMPLETE that you can use.

Comment: my question is that i made a button for play/pause a SWF file, but when the video is playing,the pause button is appeared, but when the video is end,i can't return the button to a play button symbol ! how can i check if the video is completed and force the button to be a play button ??